# The memcache extension must be loaded for using this backend

Tags: php, zend-framework, memcached

I got memcached installed. This is from phpinfo():

[image]

But when using it like this:

```
private static function getZendCacheMemcachedObject()
{
    $frontendOpts = array(
        'caching' => true,
        'lifetime' => 3600,
        'automatic_serialization' => true
    );

    $backendOpts = array(
        'servers' =>array(
            array(
            'host'   => 'localhost',
            'port'   => 11211,
            'weight' => 1
            )
        ),
        'compression' => false
    );

    return Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'Memcached', $frontendOpts, $backendOpts);
}

public function foo($id)
{
    $cache = self::getZendCacheMemcachedObject();
    $cacheKey = 'foo_'.$id;
    $xml = $cache->load($cacheKey);

    if (false === $xml) {
        $xml = $this->httpClient->foo();
        $cache->save($xml, $cacheKey);
    }

    return $xml;
}
```

I get this error:

```
The memcache extension must be loaded for using this backend
```

Any ideas?

Comment: FYI ZF outputs that error if `extension_loaded('memcache')` returns false, so something weird is going on with your configuration.

Comment: Well, the problem seems to be that Zend_Cache_Backend_Memcached is loading memcache library instead of memcached. Why is it called mecached when it uses memcache? Wtf.

Comment: This might help: http://serverfault.com/questions/63383/memcache-vs-memcached - looking at my phpinfo, it's certainly 'memcache' that I have installed, whereas yours is listing 'memcached'

Answer (score 41, accepted):

PHP has two Memcached libraries with confusing names :

- [Memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php)
- [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) (notice the d)

Your code needs the first one. Just do a simple `pecl uninstall memcached` and then `pecl install memcache`, modify your `php.ini` to include the appropiate .so and it should work.

Comment: Those names confuse me all the time. I never know whether I'm dealing with Memcache or Memcached or Libmemcached :P

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1742/ would be great if you gave the full instructions. What do we add to the php.ini?

Answer (score 2):

for the PHP library that you have installed, it looks like the easiest solution would be to use a different backend - if your zend framework version allows it:

Zend_Cache_Backend_Libmemcached (http://doczf.mikaelkael.fr/1.11/en/zend.cache.backends.html)

i assume that 
return Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'Memcached', $frontendOpts, $backendOpts);
turns into
return Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'Libmemcached', $frontendOpts, $backendOpts);

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue very easily. This issue happens because you didn't have the php 'memcached' extension installed. You can install it by using the following command in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install php-memcached
```

Also don't forget to restart the server after executing the above command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

or

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

or

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

And for other OS, you can search for some alternative command.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package php-memcached

Comment: Simplier solution on Ubuntu based OS. Don't forget to restart server after `$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Answer (score 2):

needs extension called php-memcached
possible solutions:
(notice that extension is different from library, there are libraries called `memcache` & `memchached`, and extension called `php-memcached`. in my case the last one was needed)
(on linux)

- to install extension:
  `sudo apt-get install php-memcached`
  this will help you.

follow below if library is also needed.

- to install library itself: `sudo apt-get install memcached`
- there is also a library containing memcached: `sudo apt-get install libmemcached-tools`

to read more and configure it you may want to check [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-memcached-on-ubuntu-16-04) and [here](https://tecadmin.net/install-memcached-with-php-on-ubuntu/)